# Get the href from innerHTML

Tags: html, reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a unit test in React to check the `href` value in a link. I have the following line of code:

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiTypography-root")[0].innerHTML;
```

This correctly returns the HTML code snippet:

```
<a class="MuiTypography-root MuiLink-root MuiLink-underlineHover MuiTypography-colorPrimary" href="www.test.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">1234 - Example</a>
```

But I am after just the href value: `www.test.com`

How can I get this value? If I try `console.log(result.href)` I get `undefined`.

Comment: because innerHTML return text, and you are trying to access href as object property

Comment: So how can I get the href value?

Comment: you have to search for href in your string OR convert that string to a valid html and retrieve href attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Use [.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method.

E.g:
`result.getAttribute('href')`

Comment: You need to re-check `document.getElementsByClassName("MuiTypography-root")[0]` line. It can not select that HTML `a` element  so it return null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var href = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiTypography-root")[0].getAttribute("href");
```

Here's the example:

```js
var href = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiTypography-root")[0].getAttribute("href");

console.log(href);
```

```html
<a class="MuiTypography-root MuiLink-root MuiLink-underlineHover MuiTypography-colorPrimary" href="www.test.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">1234 - Example</a>
```

Comment: I have added the code snippet. You can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `attributes` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

You are not looking for the inner HTML here, try to find to method that return the "attributes" of the element